# Using cfscript and a webservice object to send a SOAP call

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

I am trying to use a .NET soap API from a 3rd party.  I can do it by use it by cfsavecontent and cfhttp but I am trying to do it with a web service object.

If I do

```
<cfsavecontent>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.myUrl.com/2005/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:AuthorizationToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:Token>cb92b46a-9422-4483-a35a-345f51a6346b</ns:Token>
      </ns:AuthorizationToken>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:WebLogin>
         <ns:userLoginPlain>myUserName</ns:userLoginPlain>
         <ns:passwordPlain>myPassword</ns:passwordPlain>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:keyOverride></ns:keyOverride>
      </ns:WebLogin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</cfsavecontent>
```

I can get it to work but if I try

```
<cfscript>
    var rt = {};
    var ws = CreateObject("webservice", "Url");

     ws.Authenticate(userName=XWebUserId, password=XWebPassword);
     rt.AuthCall = xmlParse(GetSOAPResponse(ws));
     session.authToken = xmlSearch(rt.AuthCall,"//*[local-name()='Token']")[1].XmlText;

     addSOAPRequestHeader(ws, "http://www.myUrl.com/2005/", "token", session.authToken);
     ws.WebLogin(userLoginPlain='',passwordPlain='',keyOverride='');
     rt.soapresp = GetSOAPResponse(ws);
     return rt;
</cfscript>
```

I get a CF error that says `Cannot perform web service invocation WebLogin.` The detail of the error looks like:

```
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:
<pre>AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
Client faultSubcode: faultString: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at 
 myUrl.WebLogin(String userLoginPlain, String passwordPlain, String keyOverride)
 faultActor: https://ams.hftp.org/netForumHFTPTest/xweb/secure/netforumxml.asmx
 faultNode: faultDetail: {http://www.avectra.com/2005/}InvalidTokenException:
 <XWebException xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/2005/"><Message>Object reference 
  not set to an instance of an object.</Message><Number>0</Number>
  <Source>xWebClasses</Source><Line>0</Line><StackTrace> at 
 myUrl.ValidateToken(AuthorizationToken AuthToken) at 
 myuRL.netForum.xWeb.xWebSecure.xWebServiceClass.ValidateToken() at 
 myUrl.netForum.xWeb.xWebSecure.netForumXMLSecure.WebLogin(String userLoginPlain,    
 String passwordPlain, String keyOverride)</StackTrace><ErrorType>Ge... ''</pre>
```

I will build this by the cfsavecontent method if needed but I am hoping there is a script way to do this so I don't have to I have a lot of different calls to make and the script is a lot less code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this, var ws = CreateObject("webservice", "Url");  did you just type the letters, url, in for brevity, as opposed to the actual url?

Comment: BTW, for NetFORUM you should be using `WEBWebUserLogin`.  `WebLogin` was deprecated a while back.

Comment: this `addSOAPRequestHeader(ws, "http://www.myUrl.com/2005/", "token", session.authToken);` should probably be something more like `addSoapRequestHeader(ws,"http://www.avectra.com/2005/",'AuthorizationToken',session.authToken)`

Comment: Also, I have had more luck talking to xweb using CFHTTP rather than try to use CF's built in SOAP web services.

Comment: @lance, if you want to see some xweb code I've written hit me up on twitter tomorrow (@nickel4242).  its not public or I would link to it here... sorry for the noise everyone else.

Comment: @SeanCoyne Thanks for the help!!  If you could figure out a way to add it to answer I would mark it as answer.  Can't tell you how much I appreciate it